# why this python chain function call fail in?

Tags: python

I have overridden a python class method like the following:

```py
    def __dir__(self):

        # return  super().__dir__().append('extra') #failed
        # return  (super().__dir__()).append('extra') #failed

        #failed
        # rtn = super();
        # return rtn.__dir__().append('extra')

        #works
        rtn = super().__dir__()
        rtn.append('extra')
        return rtn
```

And get this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I don't mind writing a few more lines of code, but I am just curious as to why the oneliner doesn't work?

Comment: append returns None

Comment: If you really want to use oneliner, I find this works 
return super().__dir__() + ['extra']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return  super().__dir__().append('extra')
```

Fails because `append` does not return the list, it returns `None` after modifying the list it gets.

```
rtn = super();
return rtn.__dir__().append('extra')
```

Fails because you effectively split pointing at the `super()` and then calling the method, but still has the same issue as the previous example.

You final example works, because you actually capture the list and then return it after modification.